# Tomcat Unable to Enter Manager App

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8

I know similar questions have been asked before but I couldn't find a situation that people were running into that was the same as mine.

Currently my tomcat-users.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <tomcat-users>
        <user name="tomcat" password="tomcat" role="standard,manager"></user>
    </tomcat-users>
```

However when I select Manager App instead of asking me for a username and password I am immediately directed to the error 403 page.

I have been programming in java for a long time however this is really new to me.  If you are able to help out that would be amazing.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `manager-gui` which is provided default for tomcat to access manager app

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="your-username" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the name attribute with username.

Answer (score 0):

Having such an insecure password is extremely dangerous. You need to switch a a strong password immediately.

Users need the `manager-gui` role to access the HTML interface of the Manager application.

The text on the 403 error page explains all the requirements.